# Don't allow > 2mb images

Tags: php, upload, size, limit

HI!
How do i check if the users are trying to upload bigger than 2mb files? I would like to deny that and put an error message to the user who is trying to do that.

I know it is something like this, but what shall i change the 50000 to to become 2mb?

```
if ($_FILES['imagefile']['size'] > 50000 )
{
die ("ERROR: Large File Size");
}
```

Comment: You really could have asked that question much more clearly :-(

Comment: how many bytes are 2mb? thats your question

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2 MB is 2097152 bytes.

Change the 50000 to 2097152 and you're set.

Answer (score 6):

The 5,000 is the number of byes, so basically you just need to convert 2MB to bytes. 1 MB is 1024 kilobytes, and 1024 bytes is 1 kilobyte. Doing the maths, we get:

2 megabytes = 2 097 152 bytes

Basically, you can calculate this in code form

```
$maxFileSize = $MB_limit * 1024 * 1024;
```

And check that the file size does not exceed $maxFileSize.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a file field in a form, called 'upload', you can check the size of the file as follows:

`if ($_FILES['upload']['size'] > $max_upload_size) { echo "File too big"; }`

Where $max_upload_size is the maximum size you want to allow (obviously you'll want to replace the `echo` statement with a more useful error message).

You can also use the [upload_max_filesize](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) setting in the php.ini file, but this will cause your users to see a PHP error if they exceed this limit, rather than your custom error message.

Comment: Yes i know that, but what to write in the max_upload_size variabel? To fit my suggestions? 2mb? Howto ;)

Comment: 2 MB = 2048 kilobytes. 2048KB = 2097152 bytes. (Apparently.)