# Image doesn't upload to the folder (no error or warning)

Tags: php, image-processing

I have a PHP image upload code and it doesn't show any error or warning after running code but it doesn't upload image to folder or does nothing

**php**

```
    <?php

if (isset($_FILES['files'])) {
    $uploadedFiles = array();
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name) {
        $errors = array();
        $rand_name = microtime().microtime().time().microtime();
        echo $rand_name;
        $file_name = microtime().time();
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];

        if($file_type == "image/gif"){
            $sExt = ".gif";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/pjpeg"){
            $sExt = ".jpg";
        } elseif($file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/x-png"){
            $sExt = ".png";
        }
        if (!in_array($sExt, array('.gif','.jpg','.png'))) {
            $errors[] = "Image types alowed are (.gif, .jpg, .png) only!";
        }
        if ($file_size > 2097152000) {
            $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }
        $desired_dir = "user_data/";
        if (empty($errors)) {
            if (is_dir($desired_dir) == false) {
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/" . $file_name . $sExt)) {
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($file_name . $sExt, 1);
            } else {
                echo "Couldn't upload file " . $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
                $uploadedFiles[$key] = array($_FILES['files']['name'][$key], 0);
            }
        } else {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }

    foreach ($uploadedFiles as $key => $row) {
        if (!empty($row[1])) {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = $row[0];';
            eval ($codestr);
        } else {
            $codestr = '$file' . ($key+1) . ' = NULL;';
            eval ($codestr);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="for.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Attachment(s): <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple id="files" class="hidde fileInpu"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request">
```

I ran this code in NetBeans with WampServer but didn't encounter any error.

Comment: try debugging line by line, see where it fails. for starters, do a `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: @B-and-P whats `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)

Comment: if you are using netbeans and have xdebug set up, you can walk through your code line by line and debug, very useful! look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line raises questions for me:

```
$file_name = md5(uniqid("") . time());
```

Is this a function or a typo?

At no point do you check for file upload errors using `$_FILES['files']['error']` , try getting some feedback from that error array.

Also     `$file_size > 2097152000` is far too large, as a 2Mb file is infact `2097152`, see [Don't allow > 2mb images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226855/dont-allow-2mb-images) .

If you are in XHTML your `multiple` needs to be `multiple = "multiple"` , you look like XHTML as your HTML element ending is `/>`

You need to check your PHP Error log and see what's turned up. Please see [Where does PHP store the error log? (php5, apache, fastcgi, cpanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log) for more information, if you're not sure what/where the error log is.

I'm pretty sure one of these points will solve your issue.

Comment: i cant upload multiple images

Comment: hmm, that's against all the code in your example, which is geared towards multiple images in the foreach loops. can you share which issue was the cause of your original error?

Comment: when i upload multiple images total size more than 2MB images are not upload so i made increase in `$file_size > 8388608` even after making change coudn't upload